# Can I use REGINI to read and output the current permission set of a registry key?

Tags: windows, cmd, permissions, registry

I know I can modify the permissions on a reg key using REGINI, however, from my understanding, it replaces the current values rather than appends them. Can I use the utility to output the current permissions set so that I can modify just the portion I want to change and update it using REGINI? Is my understanding of the utility incorrect? Is there another method that can accomplish the same task that does not require the installation of a 3rd-party tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use REGDMP (from the Windows resource kit) to dump the current state.

Alternatively, you can use the [`Get-acl`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176838.aspx) and [`Set-acl`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/brad_rutkowski/2008/09/29/set-acl-on-registry-key/) PowerShell commands.

Comment: I used Powershell. Thanks for your help.